# Calculation of Distance from measured Acceleration vs Time

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, kinematics, acceleration, integration

I have an Accelerometer connected to a device that feeds the instant values of the acceleration in the 3 directions. I've tried to calculate the distance for a vertical movement using these values with excel (applying two times an integration), but somehow it doesn't seem to work properly.

How would be a good way to calculate the traveled distance from the measured acceleration using excel tables?

Comment: If you are only interested in vertical displacement, you only need vertical acceleration as well. Can you show us what you did?

Comment: In fact I'm interested in displacement in all directions, but for starters I've tryed so simple as possible...

Comment: I have a long list of values, and since I know the time interval for the measures, I've tried calculating first the mean of the acceleration, and then x = a * 0.5 * t^2 ... the test result is far different to the expected distance

Comment: Look at Eurequa ( http://creativemachines.cornell.edu/eureqa ) where you can take measured data, smooth, fit, and apply calculus functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting at ${position}_z$ = $z$ = 0 and $v(z) = 0$ and by tracking multiple acceleration values either with a time interval or at fixed intervals, $t$, then you can get the position.... somewhat. It will drift over time. Also, your device cannot rotate whatsoever, or else you need a gyroscope to track that and then use trigonometry to properly orient the x y and z values from the accelerometer. Assuming it's always oriented such that the $a(z)$ is always perfect vertical acceleration (if you're in a vehicle that's always flat, in which case z doesn't matter, or you're on a vertical guide rail),

$$p(z) = \int_0^t v(z) ~dt  = \iint_0^t a(z) ~dt $$

Also, from [here](http://www.avrfreaks.net/index.php?name=PNphpBB2&file=viewtopic&t=106301):

> Short answer: Forget about it.
>
> Longer answer: 
>   Unless you're on a perfectly straight rail, you will not achieve what you want to do without (a) a set of gyros; and (b) Far more accurate sensors than what you have.
>
> Accelerometers measure acceleration in the body fixed reference frame, whereas you need some displacement in an earth-fixed frame.
>
> Therefore, you need not only to integrate the accelerometers, but rotate them into the earth-fixed frame before doing the integration.
>
> This is assuming perfect sensors. MEMS sensors are far from perfect - I have written up a post on some of the errors here.
>
> Consider two errors: 
>   1. A bias on the accelerometer. 
>   2. An initial attitude (tilt) error.
>
> In addition to whatever acceleration signal there is, integrate a bias and you get a ramp error with time. Integrate the ramp and you get a quadratically increasing error with time. This will add up really, really quickly.
>
> Consider a tilt error. You'll now be measuring some of the gravity vector in the forward (or whatever) direction. Integrate this error twice and you'll have the same problem as the bias.
>
> So, my advice again is DON'T! Find another method.

Also, check [this book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1580532551) out for more detailed designs, or use whatever sensors and algorithm these guys are on:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6ijArKE8vKU

If you still want to give this a shot, use the Trapezoidal method in Excel, it's pretty easy. There's an explanation page [here](http://people.oregonstate.edu/~haggertr/487/integrate.htm) with a sample, but here's a more complete way:

```
1  Time [A]  Acceleration [B]   Velocity [C]                Distance [D]
2  0         a(z)               0                           0
3  1         a(z)               =C2+(A3-A2)*(B2+B3)/2       =D2+(B3-B2)*(C2+C3)/2
4  2         a(z)               =C3+(A4-A3)*(B3+B4)/2       =D3+(B4-B3)*(C3+C4)/2
5  3         a(z)               =C4+(A5-A4)*(B4+B5)/2       =D4+(B5-B4)*(C4+C5)/2
6  4         a(z)               =C5+(A6-A5)*(B5+B6)/2       =D5+(B6-B5)*(C5+C6)/2
7  5         a(z)               =C6+(A7-A6)*(B6+B7)/2       =D6+(B7-B6)*(C6+C7)/2
8  6         a(z)               =C7+(A8-A7)*(B7+B8)/2       =D7+(B8-B7)*(C7+C8)/2
9  7         a(z)               =C8+(A9-A8)*(B8+B9)/2       =D8+(B9-B8)*(C8+C9)/2
10 8         a(z)               =C9+(A10-A9)*(B9+B10)/2     =D9+(B10-B9)*(C9+C10)/2
11 9         a(z)               =C10+(A11-A10)*(B10+B11)/2  =D10+(B11-B10)*(C10+C11)/2
12 10        a(z)               =C11+(A12-A11)*(B11+B12)/2  =D11+(B12-B11)*(C11+C12)/2
   ...       ...                ...                         ...
```

Comment: While you are totally correct that this is not a reliable method it really depends on the application. For something like a model rocket with a large acceleration in one direction this can work nicely, where as to track the position of a person using a smartphone without GPS this is hopeless.

Comment: The model rocket will experience some amount of 'tipping' and may even reverse direction on descent, which will skew your measurements by providing smaller z accelerations than accurate, and then by adding to the position when falling, respectively. On a ground based vehicle x and y might be useful, but once you introduce suspension it really needs a gyroscope to track the roll, pitch, and yaw of the accelerometer to have much accuracy.